validation loss improvement in ConvLSTM model for prediction of ASL Images
I have been trying to build a convLSTM model for classifying ASL images into 1 of the given 29 classes in the dataset. The dataset I am using is this - https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/debashishsau/aslamerican-sign-language-aplhabet-dataset/data
The problem I am facing is related to the Validation loss and the overfitting of the model on the dataset.
Here is my code -
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, MaxPooling3D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Input, Dense, ConvLSTM2D, ConvLSTM1D, TimeDistributed, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(1, (5,5), activation = 'tanh', input_shape = (1, 128, 128, 1),
                     recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences=True, data_format="channels_last",
                     dropout = 0.2, name = "Conv1"))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), padding="same", data_format="channels_last", name = "Pool1"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(5, (3,3), activation = 'tanh', recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences=True,
                     data_format="channels_last", dropout = 0.2, name = "Conv2"))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), padding="same", data_format="channels_last", name = "Pool2"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(10, (2,3), activation = 'tanh', recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences=True,
                     data_format="channels_last", dropout = 0.2, name = "Conv3"))
# model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), padding="same", data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu", name = "Dense1"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(29, activation = "softmax", name = "Output_Layer"))

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, mode = 'min', restore_best_weights=True)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

r = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[es])

The output of the model training is this -
Epoch 1/10
1088/1088 [==============================] - 132s 107ms/step - loss: 2.8391 - accuracy: 0.1546 - val_loss: 25.4988 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
1088/1088 [==============================] - 115s 106ms/step - loss: 1.6435 - accuracy: 0.5003 - val_loss: 36.5423 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
1088/1088 [==============================] - 178s 164ms/step - loss: 1.1848 - accuracy: 0.6345 - val_loss: 39.9648 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
1088/1088 [==============================] - 124s 114ms/step - loss: 0.8638 - accuracy: 0.7272 - val_loss: 63.1288 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

The shape of X is (43500, 128, 128) which was reshaped to fit the model - (43500, 1, 128, 128, 1)
and Y shape is - (43500, 29).
Can you please suggest what I might be doing wrong here?
